# Firebase logging to console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, console.log

Do you know a better way to log JSON objects to the console in firebase? In my code I log it

`` console.log(`${req.body.event}: ${JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2)}`); ``

But the logged result is logging on multiple lines.. Would like to log it in a readable manner to the console. Any ideas? 
Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

just log the req.body. don't wrap it inside the backtick other wise it will give you [object]

for ex:

```js
console.log(req.body); // do
console.log(`req.body`) // don't
```

if want to add message with it use comma (,)
for ex:

```js
console.log('req.body', req.body);
```

Comment: that prints the object over multiple lines as well in firebase console..